# 301 Permanent Redirect of one URL to Another

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to 301 redirect one single URL to another using following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    Redirect 301 /shopby/Diningroom-furniture https://<domain name>/shopby/dining-furniture-on-rent
</IfModule>
```

But it is not working properly, it is redirecting `https://<domain name>/shopby/Diningroom-furniture` to 
`https://<domain name>/shopby/dining-furniture-on-rent?/shopby/Diningroom-furniture`

Can somebody please let me know what mistake I am doing. I tried the following code as well but getting the same results...

```
Redirect 301 /shopby/Diningroom-furniture https://<domain name>/shopby/dining-furniture-on-rent
```

Comment: 1) You say you tried 2 different redirects, but the 2 you have shown are identical.  2) If a redirect really appends the query string to the URL you have not shown us all your code, there are more redirects happening.  Maybe all that is needed is to add `[L]` after the redirect, to indicate this is the `L`ast redirect and nothing after should be processed?  PS: there are so many 301 redirect guides online, I recommend reading some guides and tutorials.

Comment: There is another internal rewriting rule intercepting here. You need to show _all_ relevant parts of your code.